# Can manage.py runserver execute npm scripts?

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I am developing a web application with `React` for frontend and `Django` for backend. I use `Webpack` to watch for changes and bundle code for React apps.

The problem is that I have to run two commands concurrently, one for React and the other one for Django:

```
webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch
./manage.py runserver
```

Is there any way to customize `runserver` command to execute the npm script, like `npm run start:dev`? When you use Node.js as a backend platform, you can do the similar job like `npm run build:client && npm run start:server`.

Comment: have you looked into grunt or gulp to run both tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't mess with the built-in management commands but you can make your own: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/.

On your place I'd leave `runserver` in place and create one to run your custom (`npm` in this case) script, i.e. with `os.execvp`.

In theory you could run two parallel subprocesses one that would execute for example `django.core.management.execute_from_command_line` and second to run your script. But it would make using tools like `pbd` impossible (which makes work very hard).

The way I do it is that I leverage Docker and Docker compose. Then when I use `docker-compose up -d` my database service, npm scripts, redis, etc run in the background (running `runserver` separately but that's another topic).

Answer (score 2):

If you are already using webpack and django, probably you can be interested in using webpack-bundle-tracker and django-webpack-loader.

Basically webpack-bundle-tracker will create an stats.json file each time the bundle is build, and django-webpack-loader will watch for those stats.json file to relaunch the dev server. This stack allows to separate the concerns between the server and the client.

There are [a couple](http://owaislone.org/blog/webpack-plus-reactjs-and-django/) of posts out there [explaining](http://blog.stratasan.com/confident-asset-deployments-webpack-django-part-4) this pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

I'm two and a half years late, but here's a management command that implements the solution that OP wanted, rather than a redirection to another solution.  It inherits from the staticfiles runserver and runs webpack concurrently in a thread.

Create this management command at `<some_app>/management/commands/my_runserver.py`:

```py
import os
import subprocess
import threading

from django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver import (
    Command as StaticFilesRunserverCommand,
)
from django.utils.autoreload import DJANGO_AUTORELOAD_ENV


class Command(StaticFilesRunserverCommand):
    """This command removes the need for two terminal windows when running runserver."""

    help = (
        "Starts a lightweight Web server for development and also serves static files. "
        "Also runs a webpack build worker in another thread."
    )

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        super().add_arguments(parser)
        parser.add_argument(
            "--webpack-command",
            dest="wp_command",
            default="webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch",
            help="This webpack build command will be run in another thread (should probably have --watch).",
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            "--webpack-quiet",
            action="store_true",
            dest="wp_quiet",
            default=False,
            help="Suppress the output of the webpack build command.",
        )

    def run(self, **options):
        """Run the server with webpack in the background."""
        if os.environ.get(DJANGO_AUTORELOAD_ENV) != "true":
            self.stdout.write("Starting webpack build thread.")
            quiet = options["wp_quiet"]
            command = options["wp_command"]
            kwargs = {"shell": True}
            if quiet:
                # if --quiet, suppress webpack command's output:
                kwargs.update({"stdin": subprocess.PIPE, "stdout": subprocess.PIPE})
            wp_thread = threading.Thread(
                target=subprocess.run, args=(command,), kwargs=kwargs
            )
            wp_thread.start()
        super(Command, self).run(**options)
```

For anyone else trying to write a command that inherits from runserver, note that you need to check for the `DJANGO_AUTORELOAD_ENV` variable to make sure you don't create a new thread every time django notices a `.py` file change. Webpack should be doing it's own auto-reloading anyway.

Use the `--webpack-command` argument to change the webpack command that runs (for example, I use `--webpack-command 'vue-cli-service build --watch'`

Use `--webpack-quiet` to disable the command's output, as it can get messy.

If you really want to override the default runserver, rename the file to `runserver.py` and make sure the app it lives in comes *before* `django.contrib.static` in your settings module's `INSTALLED_APPS`.